# how to upload files through cpanel?

Tags: php, sql

I am using godaddy for hosting and have linux hosting with cPanel account. How I will upload my css,images,js folders? What is the use of cgi-bin folder as it is already set under public_html folder?

Comment: where is `sql` in picture

Comment: Upload your project in public_html

Answer (score 0):

The better way is do not using c-panel for uploading event there is file manager. The best way is if you by using c-panel create ftp-account for your self. After that by ftp client you'll be able to upload or download what you like. Also by connecting via ftp your preferred php/html editor you'll be able to edit the files on fly.
cgi folder is dedicated for executive scripts or binaries. These scripts are executed outside of web server - execution is in core unix system.